# If I already close-voted, why doesn't it say "Close (1)"?

Tags: bug, vote-to-close

It seems I already voted [on this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75671293/analisys-windows-memory-dump-header), although the text below the question says

> Share Edit Follow Close Flag

where I expect it to show

> Share Edit Follow Close(1) Flag

or a higher number.

[image: Close]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You voted to close [sometime between March 8th and March 12th](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75671293/timeline?filter=NoVoteDetail)

It seems that insufficient people voted to close to result in the question's closure or perhaps you were outvoted by people voting to leave open.

At any rate the post left the close vote review queue and your [close vote then expired](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

> Close votes age away harmlessly if the threshold is not reached after a number of days. If the question has at least 100 views, close votes will age away after [4 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56614/what-happened-here-voted-to-close-4-days-ago-but-no-close-votes-today/97594#97594); otherwise, close votes will age away after [14 days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250223/age-close-votes-after-14-days-regardless-of-views-allowing-recasting). Each new close vote resets the timer, so all close votes must be at least 4 or 14 days old respectively before aging occurs.

Comment: Mod tools say March 8th at 14:58